Compress json file >= 60MB in Go to file tar.gz
When I compress a json file >= 60MB, I get an error that the data is insufficient and only 28MB is available.
func CreateTarGz(sourceDir, targetFile string) error {
    target, err := os.Create(targetFile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer target.Close()

    gw := gzip.NewWriter(target)
    defer gw.Close()

    tw := tar.NewWriter(gw)

    defer tw.Close()

    err = filepath.Walk(sourceDir, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        // Tạo header cho tệp
        header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, "")
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        header.Name = strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimPrefix(path, sourceDir), string(filepath.Separator))
        header.Size = info.Size()
        if err := tw.WriteHeader(header); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if info.IsDir() {
            return nil
        }

        // Mở tệp
        file, err := os.Open(path)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer file.Close()

        // Sử dụng bộ đệm để đọc tệp
        buf := make([]byte, 1024*1024*2)
        header.Size = info.Size()
        for {
            n, err := file.Read(buf)
            if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
                return err
            }
            if n == 0 {
                break
            }
            if _, err := tw.Write(buf[:n]); err != nil {
                log.Printf("failed to write %d bytes to tar for %s: %v", n, path, err)
                return err
            }
        }
        return nil
    })

    return err
}

I want to compress a tar.gz file from a folder that has a json file >= 60mb, how can I do it without errors. Currently I can only write 28mb, the rest is missing data.

It would help others understand the problem by creating a [mre]. The first thing that jumps out is that you are manually copying the file rather than using io.Copy. You are also setting header.Size multiple times, but the second is after you already write the header and looks unnecessary. Cleaning up and simplifying the code will go a long way.

Also: could you copy and paste the exact error message you see ? (translated in english, if your message is localized ...)

It's error message
"archive/tar: write too long"

Note that my json file is quite large.

@tuan.1203 60Mb is not really that large, and the fact it's json is irrelevant. write too long means you're writing more data than you put in Size, but we don't have enough information to know how you're doing that.

. As others have pointed out in the comments you can just us os.Copy to get all the bytes of a file inside your WalkDir loop.
I also noticed that you're trying to manually set the header's name and size:
header.Name = strings.TrimPrefix(strings.TrimPrefix(path, sourceDir), string(filepath.Separator))
header.Size = info.Size()

but that's already handled by:
header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, "")

Trying to manually set the name also has a negative side effect for the first iteration of the loop, for sourceDir, because you trim sourceDir down to the empty string, and then overwrite the header's name with the empty string.
Here's a minimal example I coded up based on your code (I also wrote my own comments in):
const (
    sourceDir  = "./tmp"
    targetFile = "baz.gzip"
)

fGzip, err := os.Create(targetFile)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer fGzip.Close()

wGzip := gzip.NewWriter(fGzip)
defer wGzip.Close()

wTar := tar.NewWriter(wGzip)
defer wTar.Close()

err = filepath.Walk(sourceDir, func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Create header for entry
    header, err := tar.FileInfoHeader(info, "")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := wTar.WriteHeader(header); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Don't try to write dir to Tar
    if info.IsDir() {
        return nil
    }

    // Write file to Tar
    b, err := os.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    _, err = wTar.Write(b)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
})
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

When I run that on my tmp folder:
+ tmp
  + bar
    - file1.txt
  + foo
    - file2.json

and then run tar -tzf baz.gzip, I get the expected:
tmp/
bar/
file1.txt
foo/
file2.json

Looking at the documenation for tar.Write, you're getting an ErrWriteTooLong:

Write writes to the current file in the tar archive. Write returns the error ErrWriteTooLong if more than Header.Size bytes are written after Writer.WriteHeader.

Some things to consider:

Have you tried removing the offending file and seeing if the program completes? Maybe something is wrong with that file and the info reported by WalkDir doesn't match the contents of the file.
Is the file actively being written too?
Did you try wTar.AddFS(os.DirFS(sourceDir))? It'll give you a different structure in the final tar, but if Go's code succeeds then there might be something wrong with this approach; if Go's code fails then maybe something is wrong with the file.


when i run your code, it still has the same error "archive/tar: write too long"

Note that my json file is quite large.

@tuan.1203, hmm, I added a 60MB file to my project and the code ran just fine. I updated my answer.
